# How can I change the iOS status bar color with nativescript, angular2 and typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, nativescript

So i've found this npm package: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-statusbar

But i'm not able to use a Page element since i'm using angular and typescript.

I already made this:

`this.page.backgroundSpanUnderStatusBar= true;`

But my Background color is black.

I would need the light status bar from iOS.

Is this possible right now?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You should be able to make the plugin work with the ng2 code. Might require a line or two of config but it should work. See how this user got the FAB plugin to work https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-floatingactionbutton/issues/21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following

```js
import {Component } from "angular2/core";
import frameModule = require("ui/frame");

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: `
<StackLayout orientation="vertical">
    <Label [text]="message" class="title" (tap)="message = 'OHAI'"></Label>
</StackLayout>
`,
})
export class AppComponent {
    
    ngOnInit() {
        var page = frameModule.topmost().currentPage;

        page.backgroundSpanUnderStatusBar = true;
        if(page.ios){ 
            page.ios.navBarVisibility = "always";
            var controller = page.ios.controller; 
            var navigationBar = controller.navigationBar; 
            navigationBar.barStyle = 2; // different styles from 0 to 3
        }
    }
}
```

More about the possibilities of styling the iOS navigation bar you can find in this tutorial [here](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/customizing-ios-navigation-bar-status-bar-nativescript/)

Comment: Thank you nick, but i get a undefined error. undefined is not a object controller.navigationBar

Answer (score 5):

With angular2 in nativescript you can just register and element in your component:

```ts
registerElement("StatusBar", () => require("nativescript-statusbar").StatusBar);
```

And in your view use the tag you created, in that case StatusBar:

```ts
<StatusBar ios:barStyle="light" android:barStyle="red"></StatusBar>
```

Comment: Where should we put this to use throughout the app?

Comment: Prabhakar Bhat, You should 1) open a terminal in your project directory and run command 'tns plugin add nativescript-statusbar'; 2) Put 'registerElement' to app.module.ts file outside of class AppModule; Don't forget to import registerElement with "import { registerElement } from 'nativescript-angular';" 3) Put '<StatusBar ...></StatusBar>' to the view where you want to show your status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I used 'nativescript-statusbar' package for changing status bar background in my Angular/NativeScript apps. But it leads to problems with the status bar on landscape mode.

So I found a better solution:

```
import { Page } from "ui/page";

@Component({...}) 
export class YourAnyComponent {
    public constructor(private page: Page) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.page.backgroundColor = '#2c303a';
        this.page.backgroundSpanUnderStatusBar = true;
        this.page.actionBarHidden = false; // if you want to show only statusbar or - true if you want to show both stutus bar and action bar
    }
}
```