# NativeScript - Angular ios status bar style

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript

I have been at this for a few days now, I've tried the methods in the [NativeScript documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/change-status-bar-style-ios), and attempted a few different approaches via comments on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36776844/how-can-i-change-the-ios-status-bar-color-with-nativescript-angular2-and-typesc). I have also tried using this plugin ([nativescript-statusbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-statusbar)) all to no avail.

I need to be able to change the status bar style based on whichever view the user is in, as some views will have a dark action bar, light action bar, or no action bar in either light or dark.

My device is currently set to Dark mode, when I switch over to Default mode the status bar follows whatever the system default is.

Here's my code (With all the fluff removed from the non-working examples I followed):

*my.component.tns.html*

```
<ActionBar title="Holidays For You">
  <NavigationButton (tap)="goBack()"></NavigationButton>
  <ActionItem class="action-skip" text="Skip" ios.position="right" (tap)="skip()"></ActionItem>
</ActionBar> 
<ScrollView>
  <FlexboxLayout alignItems="center" flexDirection="column" class="main">
    ...
  </FlexboxLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

*my.component.tns.scss*

```
ActionBar{
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.main{
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}
```

EDIT: component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventData } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable";
import { topmost } from "tns-core-modules/ui/frame";
import { isIOS } from "tns-core-modules/platform";
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-holiday-list',
  templateUrl: './holiday-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./holiday-list.component.scss']
})
export class HolidayListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private page: Page) {

    this.page.on(Page.loadedEvent, event => {
      if (isIOS) {
        let navigationBar = topmost().ios.controller.navigationBar;
        navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black;
      }
    })

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
   // Tried same code in here
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Tried the same code in here too.
  }

}
```

NOTE: I'm running this all using **tns preview** as I don't have a mac.

*And the result (Red box showing the issue)*

[image: issue preview]

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

### **EDIT: [Sample Repo](https://github.com/dmoptimal/nativescript-angular-ios-statusbar-issue)**

Comment: You can not set a custom color to status bar text, it is limited to either black or white. You must choose either one of them based on your ActionBar background color. Refer [this section](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/change-status-bar-style-ios#changing-the-status-bar-style-using-the-navigationbar-barstyle-property) of docs, you have to set `barStyle` upon page load.

Comment: @Manoj I think you misunderstood my question. I linked the exact documentation you're referring to, I can't get it to work. I am not trying to set the text to a specific color, I am trying to set it to black/white on different views within my app. Hope that clears up the confusion, I probably should have named the question differently, I'm new to nativescript.

Comment: I don't see you using bar style anywhere in your code. Have you set view controller based appearence in info plist to true, so you could change it for any controller.

Comment: @Manoj Hey man, I've added some more code & context to this question. I hope this helps? I updated my info.plist with the following: 
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
 <true/>

Comment: That should have solved it, can you share a sample repo?

Comment: @Manoj Hey man, I've created and uploaded an example project to github. https://github.com/dmoptimal/nativescript-angular-ios-statusbar-issue

Comment: It works on my end, except there was a TypeScript issue which will be solved by adding `declare var UIBarStyle`.